# How to set up a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, debian

I have a laptop running Ubuntu that I would like to act as a Subversion server. Both for myself to commit to locally, and for others remotely. What are the steps required to get this working? Please include steps to:

- Get and configure Apache, and necessary modules (I know there are other ways to create a SVN server, but I would like it Apache-specific)
- Configure a secure way of accessing the server (SSH/HTTPS)
- Configure a set of authorised users (as in, they must authorised to commit, but are free to browse)
- Validate the setup with an initial commit (a "Hello world" of sorts)

These steps can involve any mixture of command line or GUI application instructions. If you can, please note where instructions are specific to a particular distribution or version, and where a users' choice of a particular tool can be used instead (say, [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) instead of [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)).

Comment: Can I use Subversion server on Ubuntu, and clients on any platform? like Tortoise SVN client on windows?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Steps I've taken to make my laptop a Subversion server. Credit must go to [AlephZarro](http://alephzarro.com/blog/) for his directions [here](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth/). I now have a working SVN server (which has currently only been tested locally).

Specific setup:
    Kubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron

Requirements to follow this guide:

- apt-get package manager program
- text editor (I use kate)
- sudo access rights

1: Install Apache HTTP server and required modules:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn apache2
```

The following extra packages will be installed:

```
apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-common
```

2: Enable SSL

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo kate /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Add or check that the following is in the file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

3: Generate an SSL certificate:

```
sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
sudo /usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert /usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
```

4: Create virtual host

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/svnserver
sudo kate /etc/apache2/sites-available/svnserver
```

Change (in ports.conf):

```
"NameVirtualHost *" to "NameVirtualHost *:443"
```

and (in svnserver)

```
<VirtualHost *> to <VirtualHost *:443>
```

Add, under ServerAdmin (also in file svnserver):

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
SSLProtocol all
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
```

5: Enable the site:

```
sudo a2ensite svnserver
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To overcome warnings:

```
sudo kate /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add:

```
"ServerName $your_server_name"
```

6: Adding repository(ies):
The following setup assumes we want to host multiple repositories.
Run this for creating the first repository:

```
sudo mkdir /var/svn

REPOS=myFirstRepo
sudo svnadmin create /var/svn/$REPOS
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/svn/$REPOS
sudo chmod -R g+ws /var/svn/$REPOS
```

6.a. For more repositories: do step 6 again (changing the value of REPOS), skipping the step `mkdir /var/svn`

7: Add an authenticated user

```
sudo htpasswd -c -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd $user_name
```

8: Enable and configure WebDAV and SVN:

```
sudo kate /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf
```

Add or uncomment:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn

# for multiple repositories - see comments in file
SVNParentPath /var/svn

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
Require valid-user
SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

9: Restart apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

10: Validation:

Fired up a browser:

```
http://localhost/svn/$REPOS
https://localhost/svn/$REPOS
```

Both required a username and password. I think uncommenting:

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>

</LimitExcept>
```

in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`, would allow anonymous browsing.

The browser shows "Revision 0: /"

Commit something:

```
svn import --username $user_name anyfile.txt https://localhost/svn/$REPOS/anyfile.txt -m “Testing”
```

Accept the certificate and enter password.
Check out what you've just committed:

```
svn co --username $user_name https://localhost/svn/$REPOS
```

Following these steps (assuming I haven't made any error copy/pasting), I had a working SVN repository on my laptop.

Comment: Instructions worked perfectly on Jaunty as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Seemed to work perfectly, but I get a 403 forbidden when trying to access it, and no prompt for a password. Any hints on what could be wrong?

Comment: @korona: Accessing it in what way: running SVN commands or browsing to it?

Comment: Great set of instructions. Thank you.
I was getting a 403 Forbidden because my svn path was a symlink.

Comment: `"NameVirtualHost *" to "NameVirtualHost *:443"` is in the ports.conf while `<VirtualHost *> to <VirtualHost *:443>` is in the svnserver settings. this should be mentioned. i got pretty confused because i searched in the svnserver settings for NameVirtualHost and could not find it.

Comment: My svnserver file is empty, while my ports.conf only has `Listen 80` and the `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>...</...>`-part mentioned in step 2. Should I add the things @Wandang mentioned? And what is "ServerAdmin"? Is it something that should be in one of the files?

Comment: I think I must have done something wrong in the steps before, since using the first line in step 4 again fixed the file. Now I'm having the same issue as @korona, while browsing it at step 10 (`http://localhost/svn`). I tried using the `https` version, and it prompted me for a username and password. I typed one of those I created in step 7 (which I could only get working by adding the new username after your code, e.g.`sudo htpasswd -c -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd $user_name aske`, and without `-c` for the next users) and it failed. Now I'm unable to get prompted again.

Comment: I am however allowed to the root apparently (`http://localhost`). It only displays the folder `apache2-default/` though. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: When I try to commit I get the error:
`svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/testdirectory/anyfile.txt'
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem`

Comment: I was getting an XML file error "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem", I was using SVNPath instead of SVNParentPath with multiple repositories. Hope that helps anyone else.

Comment: make sure your svnserver.conf is like this:

Comment: Can I use this as SVN server, and Tortoise SVN client on client machines running windows?

Comment: In Debian Stretch it seems to you need to install `libapache2-mod-svn` instead of `libapache2-svn` (as the latter is no longer available).

Answer (score 2):

Afterwards, I needed to execute (within the context of the example quoted above)

$ sudo chmod g+w /var/svn/$REPOS/db/rep-cache.db

$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/svn/$REPOS/db/rep-cache.db

Otherwise I kept receiving a 409 error when committing local modifications 
(though the commitments were server side effective, I needed to follow up with local updates)

Answer (score 1):

If you get 403 forbidden when you hit the webserver it may be because you used a hostname that is not what you specified in your config file (ie localhost or 127.0.0.1). Try hitting https://whateveryousetasyourhostname instead...

Comment: Another 403 cause: set svn path to a symlink.
If your svn path is a symlink, you'll have to allow following symlinks.

Answer (score -2):

For Apache:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install apache2
```

For SSH:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install openssh-server
```

For Subversion:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install subversion subversion-tools
```

If you'd like you can combine these into one command like:

```
sudo apt-get -yq install apache2 openssh-server subversion subversion-tools
```

I can't help with the rest...

Answer (score -2):

Please write a single command on the terminal.

To open the terminal please press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and then type this command:

```
$sudo apt-get install subversion
```