# Problem setting up SVN & WebDAV in Ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu-8.10

I've followed every step posted in here:

[How to set up a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu)

I'm using Ubuntu 8.10

After firing up the browser, I get

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /svn on this server.
Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g Server at localhost Port 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That guide was following one from '07 so I'm not too surprised not everything went as planned.

Take a look at [the official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.10/serverguide/C/subversion.html) on getting it set up.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider to look at the red book, which is the official subversion documentation. I found it extremely helpful in the past.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the permissions for that folder.
I wasn't able to get them right, and the only thing that worked for me is was chmod 777 all the folders.