# SVN with Apache security

Tags: svn, security, apache, ssl

I've set up a local SVN repo with apache https access on an ubuntu machine using this example: [How to set up a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu)

Everything works great.
The next step is to allow users to access SVN over the internet. This works, but here's my question:
Currently it seems everyone can see the files.  Using TortSVN I can see everything, and it only prompts for a username/pw if I make changes.  How do I make it so nobody can see the repo or any files unless you're prompted for user/pw ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two psossibilities:
you can remove the following lines from httpd.conf:

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
</LimitExcept>
```

Or you can switch to path based authorization:.

By adding this line to your httpd-config:

```
 AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access/file
```

and placing this into your path/to/access/file:

```
[groups]
devs = developer1, developer2
mgr = manager1, manager2

[/]
* = 
@devs= rw
@mgr = r
pparker = rw
```

in the section **[groups]** you can group your users by assigning them group names

in the path section **[/]** you can assign to any path permissions either

- read only access (**r**) write
- access (**rw**)
- no access at all

The asterisk is a wildcard for matching any other user or group. Note the at-sign (**@**) for referencing groups. In this sample "pparker" is a single user.

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit your svnserve.conf file to say:

```
anon-access = none
```

This is located in the conf/ directory of your repository.
This will force a user to log in before they can even check out your repository.

Comment: This is only active for svnserve