# access svn server from other network

Tags: svn, networking, network-programming

Ok so I followed the instructions from here [svn config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu) and have set up a svn server on a debian squeeze host. Now this works so far from the same network. (eg. ip of the debian server: https://192.168.0.101/svn will work from computers in the same network). By same network here I mean we have one "real" Ip address from a provider and 5 workstations + server connected to the same router.

But we would need to permit access to the server to people from other networks (same provider or different provider). Now none of us are above beginners in networking so could you please tell us:

1. Is this even possible with the current configuration? (meaning the server does not have a "real" ip).
2. What would we need in order to achieve this? Should we ask the provider for a second ip and use it for the server ? Would that solve it ?

Comment: Your server needs to be reachable from the other hosts - at least for example respond to ping requests. So yes, you'll need to give the server a public IP (or the client a private one, using for example a VPN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router that connects your internal network to other networks needs to forward https requests to your svn server. If the external IP of the router is 10.0.0.1 and set up to forward port https (443) to 192.168.0.101 then external users would refer to the svn server as https://10.0.0.1/svn.

If you simply want to make the svn server available to another internal networks look into routing tables.

Comment: Hey @Bogdan did you make it work? I need something exactly like this.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure your router to perform NAT [1] and forward requests to port 443 (HTTPS) to the same port on your server.

Matteo

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a typical SoHo configuration you have here.

Now you have several ways to proceed:

1. You can tell your router to redirect every access to the given port to the given server (NAT).
2. You can tell your router to redirect every access to all (not otherwise redirected) ports to the given server. This is often called DMZ, although it has not much to do with the normal use of this word.
3. You can move that stuff to a server outside.