# How to install SVN server in Linux

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed SVN on my Windows server and all clients, that re connecting to it, also uses Windows.

Now, I need to install SVN server on Linux, but clients will remain on Windows.
Can some one help me in the configuration?

Comment: I believe a google search will find you answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you referring to?

Comment: @sandeepnair85 don't need that much complexity for just subversion.  Just install the svn package and use `svnserve`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-set-up-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on ubuntu then `apt-get install subversion`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Optware (IPKG) installed (on any Linux that supports it), you can simply call `ipkg install svn`.