# Beginner's Request for a Subversion Guide

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Our programming team is looking for a method of version control for all of our code. Subversion was recommended, so we decided to check it out. However, since we're all new to the idea, we're having a hard time wrapping our heads about how to go about setting up and using it.

- We are a small team of 3-5 people working together locally on Windows machines
- None of the programmers have worked with synchronization software like Subversion before
- We have access to a local machine with Ubuntu Server set up via VirtualBox
- We also have paid server hosting we can use

Is there a way to have Subversion or something similar set up on the local machine or the paid server? If so, is there an easy-to-understand guide to do it?

Comment: I feel like this is easy enough to Google, than to ask here =\. That being said, TortoiseSVN comes highly recommended.

Comment: if you decide to choose SVN over HTTP after having read about subversion and possible ways of exposing the repository I do recommend having a look at this out of the box package: http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion . It is very easy to configure properly without any special knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is the best SVN manual in my opinion. If you want to set up an SVN server, you can look here [How to set up a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The [SVN book gives](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) step by step instructions. There's a copy included with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (`Help` from the TortoiseSVN menu, or open the `TortoiseSVN_en.chm` help file in the product's `bin` folder) that even customizes it to work with that GUI. There are basic tutorials in both of them, and there are details on every aspect of setting it up, configuring it, and using it.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) since you are new to [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and version control in general.

The following introductory topics are highly recommended for novice Apache Subversion users:

- [What Is Subversion?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.whatis.html)
- [Fundamental Concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html)
- [Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html)

Since you are on Windows I strongly recommend you to consider [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) client (and it's [manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) in addition to the above docs). [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is the best choice of Subversion server solution for Windows. You can install it on one of the machines in your network and you'll have the complete Subversion server solution tied specifically for Windows and Active Directory environment.

In your question you state that *"None of the programmers have worked with synchronization software like Subversion before"*. Apache Subversion is **NOT** synchronization software, it's a centralized version-control system, as said on Apache Subversion website: *"Enterprise-class centralized version control for the masses"*. So, it's not about synchronization. It's about keeping your development process versioned, organized and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple [article](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp314/svn.html) written on SVN. But a [Cheat Sheet](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/) is always useful and quicker than the long articles if you are not interested on the internals.

Comment: I can't agree with you. Version control system is important part of development process and in-depth knowledge of the tool you use is very,ehm, helpful. Just reading some articles and cheat sheets don't provide you with the complete insight. SVNBook is strongly recommended in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can find article about install and configure

Link : http://tortoisesvn.net/support.html

You can download here : http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Your team could try to download and start an SVN [virtual appliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_appliance).
When the solution fits your needs you can move the appliance into a more robust hardware.

I love [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) as cross-platform virtualization application and it is open source.
Here (http://virtualboximages.com/Virtual.Appliance.Subversion.Trac.amd64.9.10) you can find your ready to start server.

But if you google around, there are many alternatives:

- [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: the VMs are quite outdated. Is there any up-to-date one? I.e. is there any with Apache Subversion 1.7?